# change resource path dynamically won't work in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, resources, sprite

I'm a new user of Unity, and have a trouble to load sprites.
I'm looking for a solution since many days.

I tried lots of different things to fix it but i can't...

I have a path for building resources in 'resources/building/walls/base' where there are 5 different wall sprites
I would change the resources path with this loop:

```
   public void ChargeSprite(SpriteRenderer rd, string wallname)
{
    Debug.Log(wallname);
    rd.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/building/walls/base/"+ wallname);     
}
```

if i do `Debug.Log(wallname)` it give me the right sprite names...

If i do `"Sprites/building/walls/base/leftwall"` or other name manually, it works...(check pic)

If i check rd variable in a loop, it exist each time..

So my question is: Can i change dynamically this link or not?

[Console result is good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6dtp.png)

Comment: This should work, I'm not seeing anything obvious that would be breaking it.

Comment: Same for me... It's really frustrating!

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: Just for the sake of it. Have you tried the following: 1) Creating a string variable to store your dynamic path before using it on `Resources.Load`? 2)  `Resources.Load<Sprite>(("Sprites/building/walls/base/"+ wallname).ToString ())`? 3) `Resources.Load ("Sprites/building/walls/base/"+ wallname) as Sprite`? I don't see why any of these will work because I don't personally see anything wrong with your code but it's worth a try.

Comment: Your code example has path ‘Sprites/building/walls/base/‘ and question text mentions  'resources/building/walls/base'. Your code should work if the sprite path starting from assets folder is “resources/Sprites/building/walls/base/‘.